# Why does angular parse templates before router resolved is done?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm using angular and ng-route and want to handle a simple redirect if some given resolve returns false. However, if the route's template contains ng-bind-html, an "Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context." error is triggered, even though there's no reason to load the template before the resolve. The only solution I've found is to return null (false doesn't work) from the resolve...

https://jsfiddle.net/pansay/wLkxkp5e/3/

```
.when('/abc/:id', {
        template: 'should not get here <span ng-bind-html="ctrl.someData"></span>', // if :id was not found
         controller: ['someData', function (someData) {
               this.someData = someData;
           }],
           controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        resolve: {
            someData: ['$location', function ($location) {
                // actual case: use the :id param to fetch data from some service
                // but redirect if it returns false
                $location.path('/abc');
                return false;
            }]
        }
    })
```

but that still means that the controller/template is still parsed, which doesn't seem to be the desired/documented behavior and could potentially trigger other issues... Is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return `false` from resolve, you actually indicate that **resolving is fine and returned value of `false` to be passed to scope**. So it enters that state before for a moment redirecting, with the value of false. And since the `someData` is resolved with a weird data you see exceptions etc.

What you need to do is to **prevent entering that state, if you will do a redirect**. To do that, you need to return a promise and reject it.

Like this:

```
someData: ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {
            return fetchFromSomeService.then(
               function(valueFromService) {
                   if(valueFromService === false) {
                     return $q.reject();
                   }
                   return valueFromService; 
               }
          }]
```

For your code sample you can simply do this to make it work:

```
someData: ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {
                // actual case: use the :id param to fetch data from some service
                // but redirect if it returns false
                return $q.reject();
            }]
```

Comment: You're right, it works fine with promises, I ended up implementing it like this:
`resolve: {
                postsList: ['postsService', '$location', function (postsService, $location) {
                    return postsService.getPosts().catch(function () {
                        $location.path(appUrls.home); // redirect to home if posts list not found
                    });
                }]
            }`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Can you mark this answer as answer? So, people will see this question as answered when they search. And it'll be easy for them to reach the information.

Comment: I'm not sure why my solution with .catch worked, but in another case it did not. Actually, the return value of the .catch error handler is still passed to the controller and the template is parsed.
So both from the success handler and the error handler either a rejected promise must be returned ($q.reject() like in your solution), or an error thrown. In other words, the last return value of the last handler of the chain is passed, whether from a success or an error callback, unless that return value is a rejected promise, or an error was thrown.